# Web element not found for selenium (Robot Framework) in Internet Explorer

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, robotframework, xpath-1.0

I am having trouble finding the web element on a website on Internet Explorer. The link i am trying to click shows as the following in developer tools:

```
<A href="..\appl\trackNTraceContainers.jsp" name=ContainerLink target=ContentPane>PO Search</A>
```

Also shown in the picture. [Image of the developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1hqH.png)

I tried:

```
Click Link | //a[@href="../appl/trackNTraceContainers.jsp"]
```

but keep getting error:

```
Link with locator '//a[@href="../appl/trackNTraceContainers.jsp"]' not found.
```

I have also tried: href=../appl/trackNTraceContainers.jsp
but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It seems odd that the rendered url would start with `../`.  Shouldn't the browser have resolved the relative url and translated it into whatever the actual url is?

Comment: I was wondering the same. It hasn't. When i double click on it, it copies as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for a link with an href with forward slashes, but the actual href has backslashes. Even though this looks like a filename, and on windows a forward slash and backslash are essentially the same thing, all selenium sees is characters, not filenames. `\` and `/` are not equivalent when looking at the attribute as a string of characters.

Your code should work if you search for exactly what is in the element. You will need to escape the backslash since robot will see a single backslash as an escape character:

```
Click Link | //a[@href="..\\appl\\trackNTraceContainers.jsp"]
```